Is the shift in how demons are presented in Buffy justified in universe or explained out-of-universe
I noticed what appears to be a shift in how demons are presented in Buffy the Vampire Slayer. Early in the series, demons tended to be individuals, like the Brotherhood of Seven or the Bezoar; demons have different appearances and goals, but no particular affiliation: Giles' research identifies the particular demons' goals and weaknesses to help Buffy.
Later in the series, demons are described as being part of particular demon species, like the Fyarl demon, and those species have characteristic goals and weaknesses, which Giles', et al, research to help Buffy.
Around the time of the shift from individual demons with names, to species of demons with names, the series also starts to show demons of some species are "just folks" (like Clem).
Is there any in-universe explanation of this apparent shift, or any out-of-universe explanation of why the producers decided to change how demons are presented?

In the general sense, something you can re-use is more valuable (to the writers) the longer a show runs.  The fact that S4 started the process of humanizing Spike and Anya probably also contributed.

I fail to see how this writing shift could be justified in-universe. It's not like everyone suddenly woke up and the world was altered.

It starts early-on with the simpatico Angel - with a number of vampires that you failed to mention. To me, it's as if more of the world were revealed to Buffy as time went on. (The initiative had been there some time when Buffy found out, not so?)  You could call it retcon, but I just see her growing up and coming to know and understand the challenges the world can present better.

Yeah, Buffy learning more about the complicated world is a possible in-universe answer (notice that we went from strictly evil witches to not-necessarily evil witches, too). But you'd think Giles  would have remarked on the issue.
